# Material design lite Indeterminate progress bar is not taking whole width applied to it

Tags: progress-bar, material-design-lite

I am using Indeterminate loading in one of our material lite page. 
The problem is that it is not taking whole length applied to it.

I am using div with class 'mdl-grid' and inside that I am using another div with class 'mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col'. in this inner div I am actually using progress bar div.

I am using following HTML code:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
<div class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The output of which is like:
[using-12Col-div](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/b0812a65a46892bf0bc0aa700db1aad5.png)

As you can see, it's not taking whole length of the div i.e. 100%
So, I tried with two 6 column grids and tried to add progress bar component into those like,

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
<div class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate"></div>
</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
<div class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate"></div>
</div>
```

But still it's taking same width.

The codepen for the same can be found [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXRBoz).

Any help about using inderminate progress bar to take whole length assigned to it, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are giving the *container* full  width, not the progress itself. Animations need a set width in some sense to work consistently. We opted for a hard width of 3 or 500 pixels against `.mdl-progress`.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjOMXz) that is working how you want. Simply understand  CSS Animations can get wonky with inherit widths like percentages.